# Yii2. Add attributes to GET request before submit

Tags: get, yii2, submit

I use an ActiveForm in yii2. After click on submit button I have a following GET request. How can I add the custom attributes to 'ProjectSearch' array before submition?

```
$_GET = [
    'r' => 'project/index',
    'ProjectSearch' => [
        'description_' => '',
        'categories' => '',
        'moneyrange' => '5,50',
    ],
    'sort' => '-price',
];
```

Comment: can you alter the model and include hidden fields in the form ?
can u share the model

Comment: The model is a standart SearchModel generated with gii. I can add an attribute to model and attach it to hidden input. Actually I need to put 'sort' attribute inside ProjectSearch of GET request. But I can not attach it directly(I use ButtonDropdown to render sort links and it cant be used with model). So is there any solution except creating a hidden field and using jquery in order to change value of it?

Comment: can u change the value from the controller ? after you submit the data and before you pass the data to the search function ?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into yii.activeform.js in order to know more about the events which can help you to do the above mentioned task. Like here you can use before submit:

```
$('#contact-form').on('beforeSubmit', function (e) {
//Add your part of code!
}
return true;
});
```